# Puedo instalar Android Studio en una pantalla con resolución HD? En los requisitos dice que tiene que ser FULL HD

Tags: android, studio

En los requisitos de la página oficial de Android Studio dice que la resolución de pantalla debe ser mínimo de 1280×800 píxeles. Soy nueva en programación para Android y quiero comprar una laptop que cumpla con todos los requisitos, sin embargo las que se ajustan a mi presupuesto (con un buen procesador y memoria RAM) todas son HD (1366 x 768). Alguien sabe en qué me afectaría esto a la hora de utilizar Android Studio? Por qué el mínimo tiene que ser 1280×800 píxeles?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: La única limitación en la dimensión vertical de la pantalla es que se muestra menos código  a la vez y hay que hacer scroll. Yo he tenido Android studio en una laptop con esa resolución y ha funcionado bien.

Comment: Exacto @Lobos solo tendrías esa limitación

Comment: Como bien dice el resto, la única limitación será la del `scroll` pero fuera de eso no tendrás problemas.